# Extract or Flag a list of Parent Rows in a Pivot Table based on a calculation about the Child Rows, done outside the Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

So I have a pivot table with nested rows (I can change the format if that helps) that sums up the number of Completed projects, and the number of Started, but not Completed projects by Grade.  Under each Grade is the topic (Science, English, etc.).

Just outside the pivot table (in Column A) I have an equation `=IF(C17=0,IF(D17>=1,"Bingo!",""),"")` that helps me flag any subjects where there is a new Project started on a topic where there were none completed so far.

Is there a way for me to flag the Grades where there is a "Bingo!" based on there being one for a topic?  I can't just use the same IF statement because if there is a Completed project on any topic, it won't flag it as a Bingo. In the example below I'd like to call out Grade 3 and 4 for having new projects in previously-untapped areas.  Imagine I have thousands of Grades and can't do this manually.

Edit: Open to handling this any other way, even without a pivot table if you have ideas...

[image: example]